# What should I do when getting a "Socket Error #10054 Connection reset by peer"

Tags: delphi, indy

I get this error sometimes(seldom in fact): "Socket Error #10054 Connection reset by peer".
My client side application catches this error. Very well.

But what would be better to do when getting this error? I think telling the user to restarting the program isn't be so nice(or is it the only way?).

Comment: Thank you. I just doing some search but I don't try "recover". What should I do now? Deleting the question?

Comment: If you no longer believe your question needs answering, then feel free to delete it.

Comment: warn user that connection was dropped and ask if s/he wants to try to reestablish.